# Ocaml: weighted graph

Tags: graph, ocaml

I'm working on Ocaml but i'm still a beginner so i have to ask a little help. 
 
Following book instructions, i created a type that represent an oriented graph:

```
type 'a graph = Gr of ('a * 'a) list;;
let grafo1 = Gr [(1,2);(1,3);(1,4);(2,6);(3,5);(4,6);(6,5);(6,7);(5,4)];;
```

Then i created a succ function that take a node as input and it give me his successor as output:

```
let succ (Gr arcs) n=
  let rec aux = function
     [] -> []
    | (x,y):: rest ->
        if n = x then y::(aux rest)
        else aux rest 
  in aux arcs;;
```

Then i used the succ function to make a modified BFS function, this function show me if exists a path between 2 nodes:

```
let bfs graph p start =
  let rec search visited = function
         [] -> raise Nodo_not_reachable
     |n:: rest ->
           if List.mem n visited
           then search visited rest
           else if p n then n
           else search (n::visited) (rest @ (succ graph n))
  in search [] [start];;
```

I call the function using this code:

```
bfs grafo1 (function x -> x=7) 1;;
```

The function give true as output if exist a path between node 1 and node 7.
Now, i want to do the same things but with a WEIGHTED graph, so i created a new type, a list where each element is composed by 3 numbers instead 2: (node start - wiegh of edge - node arrive):

```
type 'b graph_w = Grw of ('b * 'b * 'b) list;;

let grafo2 =  Grw [(1,3,2);(1,1,5);(2,2,3);(5,5,3);(5,4,6);(3,1,6);(3,7,4);(6,2,7);(4,4,6)];;
```

So, i modified my previous function to adapt them on this type:

```
let succ_w (Grw arcs) n=
   let rec aux = function
       []-> []
     | (x,y,z)::rest ->
         if n=x then z::(aux rest)
         else aux rest
  in aux arcs;;

let bfs_w graph_w p start =
       let rec search visited = function
            [] -> raise Nodo_non_raggiungibile
       |n:: rest ->
         if find n visited
         then search visited rest
         else if p n then n
         else search (n::visited) (rest @ (succ_w graph_w n))
      in search [] [start];;
```

(Since i can't use List.mem on this new type, i declared a function called find that give me true as output if an element (x,y,z) is contained on a list):

```
let rec find (x,y,z) = function
    [] -> false
  | (v,c,p)::rest -> if (x=v) then true else find (x,y,z) rest;;

find (2,3,1) [(2,2,3);(4,5,6);(8,9,0)];;
```

Now a little problem, someone can tell me how can i call my bfs_w function using the new graph type?
Using

```
 bfs_w grafo2 (function x -> x=7) 1;;
```

I get the following error:

```
This expression has type int graph_w but an expression was expected of type ('a * 'b * 'c) graph_w
```

/--------------------------------/

Okay now the function work correctly thx ^^, but there is another problem: since i want to solve the longhest path problem using bfs (given a start node and a stop node, say true if exists a path between the nodes with a least weight k) i have to implement the (x,y,z) format on my function, so i tried something like this: (is the same function that you suggest but with (x,y,z) instead n:

```
    let bfs_w2 graph_w start stop =
       let rec search visited = function
         | [] -> raise Node_not_Reachable
         | (v,c,p) :: rest ->
              if (find (v,c,p) visited) then search visited rest 
               else if v = stop then true
              else search ((v,c,p)::visited) (rest @ (succ_w graph_w    (v,c,p))) in
         search [] [start];;
```

When i declare the function:

```
     bfs_w2 grafo2 1 4;;
```

or

```
     bfs_w2 grafo2 (function x -> x=4) 1;;
```

i met the same error on "grafo2":

```
        This expression has type int graph_w
```

but an expression was expected of type ('a * 'b * 'c) graph_w

I can't understand where the problem is, the function is almost identical to the one wich you suggest.

ps: i even tried this but i met same result:

```
      let bfs_w2 graph_w p start  =
          let rec search visited = function
             | [] -> raise Nodo_not_reachable
             | (x,y,z) :: rest ->
                 if (List.mem (x,y,z) visited) then search visited rest 
                 else if p (x,y,z) then (x,y,z) 
                 else search ((x,y,z)::visited) (rest @ (succ_w graph_w (x,y,z))) in
         search [] [start];;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all let me define the model of you graph, so that we can speak the same language. You're using a edge list to represent a graph. For a graph of type `'a graph` we will say that `'a` is `node`, and `'a * 'a = node * node` is an edge. So the graph itself is represented as `edge list`. To represent a weighted graph you're using edges that are labeled with weights, so the `edge` has now type `node * weight * node`, where `weight` has type `int`.

Now, let's go to your problem. If you look carefully in `bfs` implementation you will notice, that `visited` has type `node list` (i.e., `int list`), not `edge list`. And you're applying your predicate to a value of type `node`, not to an edge. 
The same should be true to your `bfs_w` function. But here you, for some reason, decided that you're storing edges in a `visited` list, and used you own `find` function, instead of `List.mem` that is fully applicable here.

```
let bfs_w graph_w p start =
  let rec search visited = function
    | [] -> raise Not_found
    | n :: rest ->
      if List.mem n visited
      then search visited rest
      else if p n then n
      else search (n::visited) (rest @ (succ_w graph_w n)) in
  search [] [start]
```

This implementation will have a correct type, expecting a user predicate that accepts a value of type `node`.